# how to repair corrupted VMVare virtual machine file (.vmdk)

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have a WMWare ESXi virtual machine file that is corrupted after a power failure.

VMWare does not recognize it as a valid .vmdk file

also When I try this command:

```
vmkfstools --fix check "myfile.vmdk"
```

VMWare returns with this error:

```
DiskLib_Check() failed for source disk 'myfile.vmdk': The file specified is not a virtual disk (15).
```

Also I tried some repair softwares like **Stellar Phoenix VirtualMachine** DataRecovery, and they can browse the virtual machine files and directories. But I can not buy the full version and extract the files, because of us sanctions over my country!!!

Comment: You should restore from last known good backup.

Comment: there is no backup

Comment: 1) where do you live??????????
2) /usr/bin/vmware-vdiskmanager -R <path of the vmdk(virtual disk)>  - it is available in workstation hopefully you got it....

Comment: I live in Iran. this command is not for ESXi. it works on workstation:(

Comment: Maybe this issue occurs when the .vmdk descriptor file for the virtual machine boot disk is corrupt or missing. For more information https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016838